# how to add firebase server key in One signal.?

Tags: android, firebase, webview, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to add Firebase Server key and sender id in One Signal configurations but when I click continue its throwing an error "You are unauthorized to access this endpoint". any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you please post a screenshot of what you are seeing. 

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key

Comment: @punit are you sure you are selecting the same app from firebase console?